# Two numerical monoids are isomorphic iff they are equal

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

A *numerical monoid* (or *numerical semigroup*) is a submonoid $S$ of the additive monoid $(\mathbb N, +)$ of non-negative integers with the property that the set $\mathbb N \setminus S$ is finite.

It is folklore that two numerical monoids are (monoid-)isomorphic [if and] only if they are equal. I know at least a couple of proofs of this result, but **what about a reference?** For instance, the conclusion follows from the following facts:

- In the category of cancellative commutative monoids, every homomorphism extends to a (group) homomorphism of the corresponding quotient groups (see, e.g., Lemma 11.20 in J.C. Rosales and P.A. García-Sánchez, *Numerical Semigroups*, Dev. Math. **20**, Springer, 2009).
- The quotient group of a numerical monoid is the additive group $(\mathbb Z, +)$ of the integers.
- The group endomorphisms of $(\mathbb Z, +)$ are the dilation maps.

A more direct proof is using that any two coprime elements in a numerical monoid $S$ generate every sufficiently large element of $S$ (by a corollary of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)).

Comment: I would have seen more directly as seeing $\mathbf{N}$ as a completion (e.g., it consists of $\{0\}$ those $n$ in the enveloping group such that $mn\in S$ for some $m\ge 1$). And $\mathbf{N}$ has a trivial automorphism group. (I don't know the name of the analogue of the integral closure of a commutative ring, which here gives the inclusion $S\subset\mathbf{N}$.)

Comment: @YCor, I think it is usually called the normalization.

Comment: Salvo, I think what you call "homomorphism" is usually called "endomorphism" (= homomorphism from something to itself).

Comment: @YCor As for your comment about the name of the analogue of the integral closure of a commutative ring: In some circles, the *integral closure* of a cancellative commutative monoid $H$ (written multiplicatively) is the set of all $x$ in the quotient group such that $x^n \in H$ for some non-negative integer $n$. (In particular, $(\mathbb N, +)$ is the integral closure of any numerical monoid.) As for your 2nd comment: Mea culpa, I've just edited and changed "homo" to "endo".

Comment: I didn't find it in Redei's classic book.  Many papers seem to observe this fact but don't attribute it too anybody. I didn't see it in Rosales and Garcia's numerical semigroups book. I didn't look at Grillet.

Comment: A proof can be found in Lemma 3.4 of this paper https://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_doc.php?p=2013&t=pap but it must be older

Comment: This is essentially in https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/101056/CzechMathJ_21-1971-4_4.pdf but not explicit. It follows from Corollary 4 and see the discussion after Prop 6.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks for the refs. I'll content myself with Sasaki and Tamura's 1971 paper. As you note in your last comment, the result is an immediate consequence of their Corollary 4 (cf. the first proof outlined in the OP).

Comment: I found what I think is the first paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest reference for this seems to be Theorem 3 of Higgins, John C. Representing N-semigroups. Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 1 (1969), 115–125.   In this theorem, he proves an essentially equivalent result.  He proves if $K$ and $L$ are submonoids of N and there is as surjective homomorphism from $K$ to $L$, then $K$ and $L$ are both integral multiples of a numerical semigroup $K'$.  Hence if $K$ and $L$ are numerical, they are both equal to $K'$.