# Every homomorphism between (rational) Puiseux monoids is multiplication by a non-negative rational

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let a (*rational*) *Puiseux monoid* be a non-trivial submonoid of the non-negative rational numbers under (the usual operation of) addition. It is not difficult to show that, if $f \colon H \to K$ is a (monoid) homomorphism between Puiseux monoids, then there exists a rational number $r \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = r x$ for every $x \in H$.

*Proof.* Set $H^+ := H \setminus \{0\}$ and pick $p, q \in H^+$ (since $f$ maps $0$ to $0$, we can focus on the positive elements). There then exist positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that $p = a/b$ and $q = m/n$. It follows that
$$
mb f(p) = f(mbp) = f(ma) = f(naq) = na f(q),
$$
and hence $f(p)/p = f(q)/q$. That is, the function $H^+ \to \mathbb Q_{\ge 0} \colon x \mapsto f(x)/x$ is constant. []

> **Question.** The result, along with a slighly more complicated proof, appears as Proposition 3.2(1) in [F. Gotti, [Puiseux monoids and transfer homomorphisms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186931830512X), J. Algebra 516 (2018), 95–114], but I feel it must be older. Do you know of any reference that supports my feeling?

Note that the case of numerical monoids (that is, submonoids of $(\mathbb N, +)$ with finite complement in $\mathbb N$) is covered by Theorem 3.2 in [J.C. Higgins, [Representing $N$-semigroups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/97A8C1AF24B4F5A42860F2B9AB7051A7/S0004972700041320a.pdf/representing_nsemigroups.pdf), Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 1 (1969), 115–125], as I learned from [Benjamin Steinberg's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437702/16537) in [another thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/437667/16537) some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be Corollary 4 of the paper [Morio Sasaki, Takayuki Tamura, Positive rational semigroups and commutative power joined cancellative semigroups without idempotent
Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal, Vol. 21 (1971), No. 4, 567–576](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/101056/CzechMathJ_21-1971-4_4.pdf) that I mentioned in the comments to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks! Corollary 4 in Sasaki and Tamura's paper does indeed _imply_ the result in the OP, after noticing that a monoid homomorphism between Puiseux monoids must either be identically zero or map positive rationals to positive rationals (and hence restrict, in the terminology of Sasaki and Tamura, to a semigroup homomorphism of positive rational semigroups). Before asking here, I had the term "rational semigroup" in mind but couldn't remember why...

Comment: I am confused.  I think what they mean by positive rational semigroup is exactly puiseux monoids (except  without the identity) and Cor 4 says every homomorphism between them is given by multiplication by a rational

Comment: I think that, by the term "positive rational semigroup", Sasaki and Tamura mean a (non-empty) subsemigroup of the _positive_ rational numbers under addition. Corollary 4 in their paper says that any homomorphism between positive rational semigroups is in fact an _isomorphism_ (of the form $x \mapsto rx$, where $r$ is a positive rational number). This is not the case with Puiseux monoids, but only because it is missing the zero homomorphism.

Comment: So, to recover the result in the OP from Sasaki and Tamura's corollary, I think one should first argue (as trivial as it may be) that a monoid hom $f \colon H \to K$ between Puiseux monoids restricts to a sgrp hom between the "positive cones" of $H$ and $K$, *unless $f$ is identically zero*.

Comment: @SalvoTringali, yes.  This is easy to see though since any two elements have a common multiple and so if one element goes to 0 they all do.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just wanted to emphasize that the result in the OP is not _exactly_ the same as Corollary 4 in Sasaki and Tamura's paper. It is rather that the former is a straightforward corollary of the latter.